# Z3 extra conditions(ite clause) in array model, when multiple array in record type

Tags: arrays, record, z3, smt

I have encountered some unexpected behaviour in z3 when a record contains multiple named arrays of the same type:

```
(declare-datatypes () ((Record_lengths (Record_lengths (array (Array Int Int))))))
(declare-datatypes () ((ROI (ROI (array (Array Int Int))))))
(declare-datatypes () ((Record (Record (lengths Record_lengths) (roi ROI)))))
(declare-fun rec () Record)
(assert (= (select (array (lengths rec)) 1) 0))
(get-model)
```

I've expected that there will be one solution, where rec.lengths[1]=0, all the others are default or random values. However the `lengths` selector always got an extra ite clause:

```
(model 
  (define-fun rec () Record
    (Record (Record_lengths (_ as-array k!1)) (ROI (_ as-array k!0))))
  (define-fun k!0 ((x!0 Int)) Int
    (ite (= x!0 2) 4
      4))
  (define-fun k!1 ((x!0 Int)) Int
    (ite (= x!0 1) 0
    (ite (= x!0 2) 3 ;this is unexpected
      0)))
)
```

It seems the number of these extra clauses is in some kind of relation with the number of the same array types in a record.
Like in this example: `Record_lengths` and `ROI` has the same type, and if I add more `ROI` type to `Record` then the extra clauses count increase too.

Here is a permalink of the example:
https://rise4fun.com/Z3/geoo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SMT solvers make no guarantee that the generated models are "minimum" in any sense. So long as the model they generate satisfies all your constraints, of course.

Having said that, you can use the option for partial models and get "smaller" examples. I'm putting smaller in quotes, because, again, there's no notion of a minimum here; what the solver considers part of the model and what can be skipped can vary depending on the heuristics, amongst other things. You can add:

```
(set-option :model.partial true)
```

to the top of your script to see what impact that would have.

Comment: model.partial option doesn't help much..
Where do this extra condition and its concrete values come from? Is it related to the array theorem or the terms are transformed this way by the solver during the model creation?